# Spring MVC application SiteMesh 3 Configuration for JSP files outside WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, jsp, sitemesh

In a spring MVC application i tried to use sitemesh 3 with java configurations. but it only render template for jsp files inside WEB-INF.

[image]

```
public class MySiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
    @Override
    protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
        builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/decorators/default.jsp").
                addDecoratorPath("/index.jsp", "/decorators/default.jsp");
    }

}
```

Configuration File

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[]{new ErrorHandlerFilter(), new MySiteMeshFilter()};
}
```

My Problem is sitemesh 3 working for login.jsp  But not for index.jsp?

Comment: Because the site mesh filter is, due to the way you configure it, only bound to request handled by the `DispatcherServlet` all other requests aren't processed. The `index.jsp` isn't handled/served through the `DispatcherServlet` and thus doesn't fall under the control of the site mesh filter. If you want that configure it manually and add it for the `/*` path (each request) instead of only the `DispatcherServler`.

Comment: got that point. But Not clear about how to manually add it?

Comment: Write a fresh `WebApplicationInitializer` which in the `onStartup` registers your filter.